# Subclass method as property doesn't exist in instantiated object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, state-pattern

I'm writing a State Pattern, and the methods that are properties of the different states that I have written as subclasses don't seem to exist in the instantiated State object.

Help?

The part of the code that doesn't work is something like this:

```
var Main,
    Active,
    Inactive;

Main = (function() {
  function Main() {
    // Construct Main object
    this.currentStatus = new Inactive();
  }
  return Main;

})();

Active = (function() {
  function Active() {
    // Construct Active object
  }
  Active.prototype.deactivate = function() {
    // Deactivate
  }
  Active.prototype.activate = function() {
    // Do nothing
  }
  return Active;
})();
Active.prototype = Object.create(Main.prototype);
Active.prototype.constructor = Active;

Inactive = (function() {
  function Inactive() {
    // Construct Inactive object
  }
  Inactive.prototype.deactivate = function() {
    // Do nothing
  }
  Inactive.prototype.activate = function() {
    // Activate
  }
  return Inactive;
})();
Inactive.prototype = Object.create(Main.prototype);
Inactive.prototype.constructor = Inactive;

var object = new Main();

// This doesn't work
object.currentStatus.activate;
```

Comment: But it's defined on line 29, or do you mean I should place Main right after Active and Inactive?

Comment: To me it seems like chicken-and-egg problem: you want `Inactive` to extend `Main` and at the same time `Main` uses `Inactive` as composition object in the constructor.

Comment: I see your point, but the browser seems to have no problem instantiating `Inactive` inside `Main`. Where it fails is recognizing that the `activate` method exists, or is it because it is creating an infinite loop that's why it fails in doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `activate` method in `object.currentStatus` because you are reassigning `Inactive.prototype` on line 41. You need to do this *before* extending the prototype with more methods:

```
Inactive = (function() {
  function Inactive() {
    // Construct Inactive object
  }

  Inactive.prototype = Object.create(Main.prototype);
  Inactive.prototype.constructor = Inactive;

  Inactive.prototype.deactivate = function() {
    // Do nothing
  }
  Inactive.prototype.activate = function() {
    // Activate
  }
  return Inactive;
})();
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/beqofigihu/edit?js,console

Same is true for `Active` class.